# Bespoke CMS or 3rd Party?

Tags: php, python, zend-framework, content-management-system

I am planning a side project and I want to know your experiences with CMS builds. The project is a fairly straightforward CMS with no e-commerce functionality needed. I know I can build something like this using Zend Framework quite simply. As it is a side project I don't want to spending time doing the tedious stuff like building and styling the dashboard and I want to focus on doing the bits that are bespoke and important. So I am tempted to use a 3rd party CMS like Symphony or even going in the direction of TurboGears or Django as I have been looking for an excuse to get on with a Python build for ages.

My question is it best to 're-invent the wheel' using Zend Framework which could add an unnecessary overhead to development time, or go with the untried and untested (by me) and cut out the backend design. I like the second option but I am worried that the time taken learning a new platform could also add an unnecessary overhead. Both choices seem to have upsides and downsides.

Any advice, suggestions or personal experiences that can help me here?

Comment: What is best **for you** depends on many factors and can't be reasonably answered without detailed consultation.

Comment: Thanks @deceze I am not looking for a definitive answer here, just peoples personal experiences that can help me make an informed choice.

Comment: Its something like do something to learn Vs do only what you have learned. If you have enough time then go for something new otherwise use your skills.

Comment: You are right @dev getting paid to learn is the best thing about being a web dev. I am tempted to go down the TurboGears route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience you always need to keep your options open. People always decide they want new features down the line, and if those people are not coders they will not be able to appreciate that their requirements in the beginning have now made it very difficult for you to implement their new ideas.

[Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/), [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/), [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) and [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) IMO are all quite similar in that you they give you great tools to build your application from the bottom-up. I.e. you will need to define your entities, their fields and relationships etc. They abstract over stuff like database design but ultimately you will still need to write a lot of everyday stuff, like login systems and backend interfaces (even if there are plugins available which make this easier).

Lots of people (myself included) have used [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) with some custom themes/plugins to make it do various things. It is super easy to get up and running, the community support is great and if your needs are pretty normal then you may find it the quickest way of achieving what you want. However Wordpress is definitely **not** what I would call a *framework*. It is ultimately designed with blog-type sites in mind and making it do anything other than that gets messy and just feels wrong.

I like [Symphony CMS](http://symphony-cms.com/) (not to be confused with Symfony Framework) a lot, it is fast and gives you the blank slate approach of a framework with nice web interfaces which generate most of your code for you. You will need to write your templates in XSLT which is a bit frustrating, and in general there is quite a learning curve to get over before you can really appreciate the power of the framework.

Comment: Comprehensive answer! Having done a million and one Wordpress builds, it is not appropriate for this project. Symphony CMS is a nice system, but yes I am worried about the learning curve. I am a backend developer in my day job so low level programming does not worry me.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Symfony would be just what you're looking for - with the recent Symfony 2 release, it's also very easy and convenient to integrate additional libraries like Zend, so you can have the best of both worlds for any custom components.

That said, the studio I work for run all our CMS work as Zend apps, so we can fine tune the content management process as needed etc.